# Is there a possible way to connect and control a website with mobile app?

Tags: c#, reactjs, sockets, web, mobile

My idea is a clickable dartboard mobile app which can connect to a webapp, and if you click on a dartboard tile the point shows on the website.

I would use mainly React and C#, maybe it is doable with socket? Is there any tutorial for these kind of lobbies and connecting?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome ! For real-time applications you can indeed use WebSocket. I recommand using a existing framework, if it's C# [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is what you want, you can use it in C# applications and Javascript ([tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)).

You may also want to look into [.NET Maui Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/maui?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=windows) if you want to create a mobile app with HTML/CSS.